# Image button javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml

quick question, how do I have an image cover the whole button in fxml.

So all that is visible of the button is the border. For some reason when I try to resize the image to fit the button automatically resizes to. I was using scene builder.
I am using FXML.

The button size is prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="50.999900000002526".

Remember I do not want to see the background of the button. I want it to be covered by an image.

Thx soo much, you guys have been a big help.

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you have attempted, in order to guide you to an answer.  The image should be the entire button, but you should check out the button's padding, or just set all sides to 0.

Comment: @Lasagna I thought it was so simple I didnt need code , sorry.  I dont think I need code all I have is a button with imageview.

Comment: People on this site like it when you add code, and show everyone that you have "Tried to attempt" the problem, instead of just wanting answers.  This is just to let you know so that your question doesn't get downvoted, which sucks when you just want to learn something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is to work with the `padding`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setPadding-javafx.geometry.Insets-

> ## setPadding

```
public final void setPadding(Insets value);
```

> Sets the value of the property padding.
>
> Property description:
>   The top, right, bottom, and left padding around the region's content. This space will be included in the calculation of the region's minimum and preferred sizes. By default padding is Insets.EMPTY. Setting the value to null should be avoided.

it doesn't mention a default, but you can get this easily by typing `button.getPadding();`

I decided to test this myself, and got a value of

```
 Insets [top=4.0, right=8.0, bottom=4.0, left=8.0]
```

which is why you are having the issue with it not filling up.  Resizing affects the button, the graphic is a part of it.

---

Next we will have to define our insets to get the desired affect.

To define our padding, we need to look at the insets

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Insets.html

there is a static Field for `Empty` so lets use that.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setGraphic(new ImageView("image"));
btn.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
```

will produce the desired affect, and produces a result of

```
Insets [top=0.0, right=0.0, bottom=0.0, left=0.0]
```

HOWEVER...  There is still a border, which is possibly only there when in focus...

If you want to get rid of the border, read below.

---

I decided to test if a negative value would work, and indeed -1 will work.

**Essentially, if you give the insets a -1 value it will cut off the border around the button, so the button is essentially an image**

---

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
    btn.setPadding(new Insets(-1,-1,-1,-1));
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println(btn.getPadding());
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Button Image!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}